# getting the error; attributeerror: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'delete_rows' openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

i'm writing code for a too to perform GIS functions to an input of an excel sheet. sometimes the excel sheet will come in and have 2 separate rows across the top for its attributes fields, and when there is 2, I need to delete the top row. the value of cell A1 will be naming if I need to do this

I tried writing code to check this and delete it as below;

```
openpyxl

import arcpy, os, sys, csv, openpyxl

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Yanko's tool"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True



excel = r"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Yanko's tool\Yanko's Duplicate tool\Construction_table_Example.xlsx"
layer = r"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Yanko's tool\Yanko's Duplicate tool\Example_Polygons.shp"
output = r"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Yanko's tool\\Yanko's Duplicate tool"

book = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel)
book.get_sheet_by_name("Construction Table format")




if ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value == "Naming":
    ws.delete_rows(1, 1)
book.save
book.close
```

it should just delete the first row if the if function passes true, but I get the error;

Warning

```
(from warnings module):
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 310
    warn(msg)
UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ronan.corrigan\Desktop\Yanko's tool\Yanko's Duplicate tool\Yanko's Tool.py", line 31, in <module>
    ws.delete_rows(1, 1)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'delete_rows'
```

any help in figuring out what I've done wrong would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the **Full Traceback**.

Comment: Check your version of openpyxl.

Comment: I installed openpyxl like a month ago. I've upgraded it now either way and it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, according to the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.get_sheet_by_name), the `get_sheet_by_name` function is deprecated, and you should just be using the sheet name to get the function:

```
book["Construction Table format"]
```

Another thing to note, in your code I don't see you setting that `ws` value, which should be set to whatever sheet object is returned. If you're setting it somewhere else, so it may be possible that you are using a different sheet object which doesn't have that function

```
ws=book["Construction Table format"]
```

Other than that you'd have to share the stack trace to give a better understanding of what's breaking

Comment: sorry, no idea how I copied it in without the ws defined. I do have it defined, but I've redefined it using the way you said and it still has the error.

Comment: I had Ws defined before, don't know how I copied without it. using your method to define ws gives the same error. not sure what the stack trace is but the full error message is;
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\(openpyxlpath)\reader\worksheet.py", line 310
    warn(msg)
UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:(path)\Yanko's Tool.py", line 31, in <module>
    ws.delete_rows(1, 1)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'delete_rows

Comment: What version of openpyxl are you using?

Comment: 2.6.2 is the version im using. the esri software im using it through (GIS) installs python 2.7